# Why are all table elements thrown in the first array-index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, html-table

I use Cheer.io to crawl dates from a table. The page is setup like this:

```
 <tr>
      <td>*other values*</td>
      <td>16-12-2017</td>
      <td>*other values*</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>*other values*</td>
      <td>14-12-2017</td>
      <td>*other values*</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>*other values*</td>
      <td>12-12-2017</td>
      <td>*other values*</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>*other values*</td>
      <td>12-12-2017</td>
      <td>*other values*</td>
    </tr>
```

Whenever I execute this code:

```
let date= $('tr td:nth-child(2)').text();
jsonarr.push(date)
console.log(jsonarr);
```

all dates are just thrown in one array-index. How can i get every date in its own index?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

As per [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) documentation

> **Get the combined text contents of each element** in the set of matched
>   elements, including their descendants, or set the text contents of the
>   matched elements.

You need to use `map` and `get`

```
var date= $('tr td:nth-child(2)').map( function(){ 
   return $(this).text() 
}).get();
console.log(date);
```

**Demo**

```js
var date= $('tr td:nth-child(2)').map( function(){ return $(this).text() }).get();
console.log(date);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>*other values*</td>
    <td>16-12-2017</td>
    <td>*other values*</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>*other values*</td>
    <td>14-12-2017</td>
    <td>*other values*</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>*other values*</td>
    <td>12-12-2017</td>
    <td>*other values*</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>*other values*</td>
    <td>12-12-2017</td>
    <td>*other values*</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `.text()`, which creates an single, concatenated string of the text content of the matched elements.

Instead create an array using `.map().toArray()`.

```
let date= $('tr td:nth-child(2)').map((i, el) => el.textContent).toArray();
console.log(date);
```

---

And of course you don't need jQuery to do this.

```
let date= Array.from(
   document.querySelectorAll('tr td:nth-child(2)'), el=>el.textContent
);
console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let dates = [];
$('tr td:nth-child(2)').each(function(){ dates.push($(this).text()); });
```